# View/Edit File Headers

Tags: header

I'm conducting reserach on malformed archives and this one exploit ( CVE-2012-1459 ) talkes about manipulating the header information of the archive. I have a rough understanding of all of this and would like to clear it up.

1. Every file has header information that contains byte length and other simular stuff?
2. If the above is incorrect. What is a header?
3. How is it possible to view/edit this information?

( Any information about headers is helpfull. Information online is not clear )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many file formats have headers.  If you wanted to look at the headers for a specific file, the best option would be to grab a thorough documentation of the format, a hex editor, a calculator that does hex to dec and vice versa conversions, and a notepad for sketching stuff on.  Oftentimes, they are fairly in depth and have many levels of indirection, and understanding exactly how they fit together is fairly daunting.  Some files may have many nested headers.  Archives are an example: they typically have one header with information about the entire archive, and headers inside, one for each file, with details about the contents.

Comment: So I'm converted everything but what i dont get is something like 'Uncompressed Size' would be 'l Null Null Null'. What does that mean?

Comment: is that the letter i or the number 1?  Do they provide the number as a hex string? Can you link to the exploit page you're viewing?

Comment: Write now im just looking at a generic .zip file and its header. Its 'uncompressed size' decimal is '124 000 000 000' and it was a straight line thingy |

Comment: I think that's a pipe character.  If you'll read the format specification, you'll notice that the size is probably stored little endian (i.e. least significant byte first).  so the uncompressed size of the data is 124 bytes.  Stuff like this is why having a calculator that does hex operations quickly and easily is a huge benefit.

Comment: Ok thank you! I dont know how to convert with caculator but ill learn it.

Comment: if a number in big endian is 0x12345678, the same number in little endian is 0x78563412.

Comment: can anyone please explain what a header is?